# differential volume form under two parameterizations

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to solidify my understanding of differential volume form by integrating the same section of the unit sphere using two separate parameterizations.  With the parameterization $\varphi^{-1}_1(\phi, \theta)=(\sin\phi\sin\theta, \sin\phi\cos\theta, \cos\phi)'$, $A_1 := \{ (\phi, \theta): \phi\in (0, \pi/4), \theta \in (0,\pi)\}$, I calculate the integral according to [Amann (2009)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764374792):
$$\text{Vol}_{g, U}(A) := \int_{\varphi(A)} \sqrt{\det(D {\varphi^{-1}}'D \varphi^{-1})} da$$
which here is just
$$\text{Vol}_{g, U}(A_1) := \int_{0}^\pi \int_0^{\pi/4} |\sin \phi| ~d\phi~ d\theta \approx 0.920151.$$
Next, I use the parameterization $\varphi^{-1}_2(x,y)=(x, y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})'$, $A_1 := \{ (x,y): x\in \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right), y \in (0,\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - x^2})\}$ (which I think should be the same section of the sphere) to get
$$\text{Vol}_{g, U}(A_2) := \int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - x^2}} \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right| ~dy~ dx \approx 1.30593.$$

So, two questions:

1. Where am I going wrong here?  I think that the spherical coordinates one is okay.  I would really like an example where it matches the direct parameterization.
2. I believe that $|\sin \phi|d\phi\theta$ in its entirety is the Riemannian volume form -- is this correct?

Thanks!

Edit Oct1: I've added a photo of the region.
[image: SphereRegions]

Comment: Could you explain how, in the second integral, you arrive at a numerical value when the upper limit on the integral over $\phi$ contains $x$?

Comment: There was a typo in that integral (that I've corrected). It should be over y. (I replaced $d\phi d \theta$ with dy dx).

Comment: Please write out carefully what region of the sphere you're working with and what its projection into the $xy$-plane is. Yes, your spherical coordinates set-up is correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've added a photo!

Comment: You still don’t see the mistake? I would do the second integral in polar coordinates, but you need to check the equation of the circle!

Comment: @TedShifrin Hahahaha my goodness I see it.  Thanks so much, Ted!  I thought that I was going insane.  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TedShifrin was kind enough to lead me to my silly mistake.  An updated integral would be:
$$\text{Vol}_{g, U}(A_2) := \int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - x^2}} \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right| ~dy~ dx \approx 0.920151.$$

I'll leave this posted for anyone trying to better understand volume form!